# Django error: Tuple or struct_time argument required

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-views

I'm working on a code that gets 2 variables, showdate and viewtype. Variable data are sent both through JavaScript by POST method.

```
viewtype = send an srt

showdate = send a date from javascript
```

In this code I'm defining varibles manually, as the final operation is to query the database, returning only the "events" that begin in the parameters that are generated based on the showdate and viewtape in JSON as next:

```
{"events": [["19", "Dinner," "02 \ / 02 \ / 2016 9:00" "02 \ / 02 \ / 2016 

16:30", "0", 0,0, null , 1, null, ""], ["20", "Meeting", "02 \ / 03 \ / 

2016 18:30" "02 \ / 03 \ / 2016 19:30", "0", 0, 0, "6", 1, "LOL", ""]], 

"issort": true, "start": "02 \ / 01 \ / 2016 00:00", "end": "02 \ / 07 \ 

/ 2016 23:59 "," error ": null}
```

In this example we see that the JSON contains 2 events within "events".
Then I show the error condition and my code:
I hope you can help me, thanks.

```
   Traceback:

 File "/home/zalar1/virtualenvs/go/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django 

 /core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

149. response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/zalar1/virtualenvs/go/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django

/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
147.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/zalar1/virtualenvs/go/Project1/Apps/Calendario/views.py"      
in loadActivities
123.     ldac = listCalendar(showdate, viewtype)

File "/home/zalar1/virtualenvs/go/Project1/Apps/Calendario/views.py"
in listCalendar
71.         calc1 = int(time.strftime("%d", pytTime))

Exception Type: TypeError at /agytno/LODT
Exception Value: Tuple or struct_time argument required
```

views.py

```
def listCalendar(day, Dtype):
    pytTime = jsToPythonTime(day)

    if Dtype == "month":
        st = time.mktime(
            0, 0, 0, time.strftime("%m", pytTime),
            1, time.strftime("%Y", pytTime)
                        )

        et = time.mktime(
            0, 0, -1, time.strftime("%m", pytTime)+1,
            1, time.strftime("%Y", pytTime)
                        )

    elif Dtype == "week":
        calc1 = int(time.strftime("%d", pytTime))
        calc2 = int(time.strftime("%w", pytTime))

        if calc2 == 0:
            calc2 = 7

        monday = srt(calc1 - calc2 + 1)

        #  suppose first day of a week is monday

        st = time.mktime(
            0, 0, 0, time.strftime("%m", pytTime),
            monday, time.strftime("%Y", pytTime)
            )

        et = time.mktime(
            0, 0, -1, time.strftime("%m", pytTime),
            monday+7, time.strftime("%Y", pytTime)
            )

    elif Dtype == "day":
        st = time.mktime(
            0, 0, 0, time.strftime("%m", pytTime),
            time.strftime("%d", pytTime),
            time.strftime("%Y", pytTime)
            )
        et = time.mktime(
            0, 0, -1, time.strftime("%m", pytTime),
            time.strftime("%d", pytTime)+1,
            time.strftime("%Y", pytTime)
            )

    return listCalendarByRange(st, et)
```

tiempoConv.py

```
 def jsToPythonTime(jsDate):

     matches = re.findall('(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)', jsDate)
     matches2 = re.findall('(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)', jsDate)
     if matches == 1:
         ret = time.mktime(
                 matches[4], matches[5], 0,
                 matches[1], matches[2], matches[3]
                         )
         return ret

     elif matches2 == 2:             
         ret = time.mktime(0, 0, 0, matches2[1], matches2[2], matches2[3])
         return ret
```

Comment: You should post the only code that is relevant to your question

Comment: What is the value of `pyTime` in you `listCalender` method? The reason for the exception is `pyTime` does not have the value in correct format which `time.strftime` needs.

Comment: @Sayse Hello friend , sorry , I think in this case, to the end that has the code , all code I put relevant.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadTahir , the value of pyTime in listCalendar is the return of the function jsToPythonTime() in the tiempoConv.py file.

Comment: I've removed most of the methods that are never mentioned in your stack trace, and even then I can't figure out how you get to `calc1` since `mktime` requires a tuple of length 9

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code, the one that initially causes the issue is the fact that your `jsToPythonTime` method doesn't return anything.

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns the matches so it will never equal an integer and hence it never enters the if/elif statements..

[`time.mktime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) requires a single argument of a tuple of length 9.

You then go on to convert what you believe the time to be to a string then back to an integer which just baffles me.